# validate reCAPTCHA Key

Tags: php, regex, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to figure out the best way to sanatize and validate a reCAPTCHA key. The problem is I don't have a lot of information on how they keys are formed. I think the best way may be just to check to see if the string is 40 charicters long and contains letters,numbers,dashes, and underscores. Here's the infomation I have from the documntations.

> invalid-site-public-key: Did you make sure to copy the entire key, with all hyphens and underscores, but without any spaces? The key should be exactly 40 letters long. [Source](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html)

My public key looks like this `6Ler570SAAAAAOfjh3CNFPtuBSH_QdavHc5x_JUv` I'm just worried about writing validation that is too strict and won't let some people use the plugin that I'm writing.

This is what I'm using now but not sure if there is a better way.

```
if( $recaptcha_public_key ) {
    //validate the key
        $recaptcha_public_key = filter_var($recaptcha_public_key, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{40}/")));
    // Update value in database
    update_option( 'recaptcha_public_key', $recaptcha_public_key );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have (`"/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{40}/"`) is as strict as you're going to get.  The point of the key is that it is random - if it conformed to a strict set of formatting rules it would be easy to crack.

Without analyzing a set of public keys, it's fair to assume that each character is completely random within the set `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]`.  Even if this is assumption is incorrect and there is some more specific pattern, this would be likely to change at some point in the future so it's not a good idea to commit your application to the current pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you verifying it yourself? You aren't hitting your database with the information or displaying it on the page are you? If you are putting it on the page html encode it and that should prevent scripts form being run.

You should just send it off to the third party using http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify and it will validate it (as it states in http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html).

Comment: I'm creating a plugin for YOURLS and on the Admin page I have the users enter their private and public key which is being stored in the database until I need to retrieve the keys in order to validate the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be perfect

```
if(preg_match('#^6[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{39}$#', $key)){
    // Valid key
}
```

These are the current conditions of the keys:

- 40 characters
- Start with a "6"
- Only alphanumeric, underscore and dash
  characters

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the key does not always start with a 6, that was just an example.  

While I understand your answer was mostly around the regex validation I did want to mention as this question is 6 years old now, Google/reCAPCHA no longer uses [Secret Token Validation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token). Instead they are using [Domain Name Validation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation)

Comment: Oh I see, I was testing it the other day and it works, but I guess that was because of the Domain Name. Thanks for the info; time for me to do some updates :)

Comment: I just looked back on this and it seems both keys are still being used.